# Machine learning network design for 2D point prediction labeling

Tags: neural-networks, pytorch, architecture

I'm looking to develop a basic neural network for labeling a detected set of 2D points. I've generated a random set of 3D points within a certain radius, all of which lie on a flat plane (Y value is 0). My aim is to train the network using different perspectives of this 3D point set, and subsequently input 'n' 2D points, predicting each point's label along with a confidence score.

[image]

Using a default camera matrix and some predefined camera positions I have created a pytorch dataloader. This will generate n number of training data samples.

[image][image]

Which neural network architecture should I explore to achieve this?

Comment: at first glance, I would say that transformers would be the best fit, just to be able to handle any number of points, and treating them as a set